# ListBox Dropshadow Animation

Tags: wpf, animation, datatemplate

I have a ListBox that uses a custom control as the ListBox.ItemTemplate  DataTemplate.

I guess my first question (and the rest are relevant) is how to you create unique names for the children in a listbox?

I ask because I am attempting to invoke a ListBox.Resource Storyboard from codebehind.  The error I am getting is that the MyShadow is not found.

```
<MyControl.BitmapEffect>
    <DropShadowBitmapEffect x:Name="MyShadow" ShadowDepth="5" Opacity="0.5" Softness="0.5" />
</MyControl.BitmapEffect>
```

My xaml storyboard is

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FocusedShadow">
    <!-- Shadow Animation-->
    <DoubleAnimation
         Storyboard.TargetName="MyShadow" 
         Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth" 
         To="15" 
         Duration="0:0:.14"  />
 </Storyboard>
```

I think what I need to do is specify the Targetname as the name of the item (relating back to first question) and the TargetProperty should be MyShadow.Shadowdepth  but I don't know how to get there from here.

In code I am doing a storyboardobject.begin(this);

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem. basically, (I am thinking) that you are trying to animate before the visual tree is fully created.  I solved this by using two techniques.

first, I Raise my animate event (which fires the Trigger in my xaml) inside of a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...`), using a priority of `ApplicationIdle` (this way we are pretty sure the visual tree has been created)  also, I am calling `UpdateLayout()` before I raise the event.

second, I am accessing the object, like so: `var child = this.GetTemplatedChild("MyCanvas")` to ensure that the canvas is actually there before trying to raise my event. (not so sure this helped, but the exception went away after I added this)
here is my sample code:

```
   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
   {
      this.UpdateLayout();
      if (this.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
      {
         var bzyCanvas = this.GetTemplateChild("BusyCanvas");
         if (bzyCanvas != null)
            this.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(AnimationStarted));
      }
   }),System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

Comment: I do not think that that is my issue here as I am invoking this in a MouseOver event.  In the codebehind event I find the storyboard resource and Beginanimation.  Everything is created, it just does not know how to find the DropshadowBitmapEffect.

Comment: If I place this code (the xaml) in a mouseevent trigger in the DataTemplate it works but when I move the storyboard to the listbox resources and invoke it from code is when I get the failure.